# Why do we have to take $0$ for sugar instead of $100$ in this mixture?

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

I recently took a look at the bucket method for mixture word problems. The image has been attached as seen below.

[image]

Imagine you have $300$ gram flour-sugar mixture that has $\% 30$ of flour  and $\frac{1}{3}$ of this mixture is poured. Then, you readd the sugar as amount of poured flour-sugar mixture, which is $\frac{1}{3}$. Thereby, our equation is

$$200\cdot 30 + 100\cdot100 = 300 x$$

Which seems wrong because I took $100$ for sugar instead of $0$ according to the image. Why? Sugar is a pure substance, so it will be $100$ instead of $0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your mixture is $200$ grams of $30\%$ flour, to which you add $100$ grams of sugar.  If you want to find the amount of flour it would be $30\%$ of $200$ if you want to find the amount of sugar, it would be $70\%$ of $200 + 100\%$ of $100$

Comment: "Which seems wrong because I took 100 for sugar instead of 0 according to the image. "  Where in the image is it taking 0 sugar???  You aren't adding *water* to the mix.  You are adding *sugar* to the mix.  "Sugar is a pure substance, so it will be 100 instead of 0".  Right.  So what is the problem.

Comment: It's not wrong because you took 100% instead of 0% sugar.  (you did that part right.)  It's wrong because you put the original mixture at 30% sugar.  It is 30% *flour.  It is 70% sugar.  So $200\g \times 70\% + 100g\times 100\% = 240g$.  Your equation is difficult to understand as you are using the percentages as whole numbers, you aren't telling what units the other numbers are and what they mean and because the $x$ is not explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original mixture:  $300 g$.

Pour out $\frac 13$.  $300g\times \frac 13 = 100g$.  We remove $100g$.  $300g - 100g = 200g$.  We have $200 g$ of mixture.

The mixture is $30\%$ flour and $100\% - 30\% = 70\%$ sugar.  So we have $200g\times 30\% = 60g$ of flour and $200g \times 70% = 140g$ of sugar.

We add $100$ grams of pure sugar.

So we have $200g\times(100\% - 30\%) + 100g\times 100\% =$

$200g\times 70\% + 100g\times 100\% = $

$140g + 100g = 240g$ of sugar.

And we have $200g + 100g$ of mixture.

So the new mixture is $\frac {240}{300} = 80\%$ sugar.

.....

The $0$ percent would be if we added *water*.  But we added sugar.  Not water.